# Draw the line segment joining the centers of two circles. Where does it meet the circles?

Tags: geometry, circles

I'm trying to construct a line segment between two circles. Given each radius and $x$, $y$ center of each circle, how can I find the endpoints for the blue line segment?

[image]

Comment: You mean 'what is the formula for the _length_ of the _segment_ joining the centres of two circles'. Also, what is known? I.e., in terms of what do you want to find the expression of the length of the segment?

Comment: @user31415 No, the formula of the line, not the length of the line segment. A line with endpoints on the circumference of each circle.

Comment: If a line goes through the centers of the circles, then it must intersect the circles. Otherwise it would not be a line. If it is not exactly a line that you want the equation of, then say so. Is it a curve that is a subset of some line but not the line itself (with some 'holes', or 'jumps')?

Comment: find the line through the centers, find the intersections points with the circles, more precisely the two points that bound the line of interest, and take convex hull, that would count I think at the formula for the line segment. Alternatively represent the line through the centers parametrically, and then pick a suitable interval for the parameter to describe the line segment between the two circles. You would need three intervals if you would like to include the two line ends going away from each circle. Either way your your question seems to perplex people that try to understand its meaning

Comment: @user31415 Hopefully edit helps.

Comment: so you are looking for a formula for a dumbbell :) Find the line through $x,y$ then find the points whose distance from $x$ respectively $y$ is the corresponding radius (and pick the "inner" ones).

Comment: @MonteCarlo Your title question asks for a line, which is an object of infinite extent, and its equation is just the equation of a line through the two center points. The endpoints of a line segment (which your question body now seems to ask) is something different. Can you make your title clearer?

Comment: A line has no endpoints - it is infinite. The blue object is not a line. It is a segment. So you're searching for the coordinates of the endpoints of the blue segment.

Comment: @user31415, question was edited before your comment, and clearly stated line segment and end points for blue line.

Comment: @MonteCarlo the question body still contains "endpoints for the blue line".

Comment: @user31415 Jesus Mary and Joseph. It reads "endpoints," ergo it is NOT an infinite line. Do you want me to preface each occurrence of the word "line" with "segment" for you?

Comment: @MonteCarlo It is understandable what you mean, but it is not correct terminology, so yes, you should edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the centres of the two circles be $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$, where either $x_1 < x_2$ or $x_1 = x_2$ and $y_1 < y_2$, and radii $r_1$, $r_2$.

Suppose $x_1 = x_2$. In this case, the blue line segment is vertical, and its endpoints can easily be seen to be $(x_1, y_1 + r_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2 - r_2) = (x_1, y_2 - r_2)$.

Now suppose $x_1 < x_2$. By shifting horizontally and vertically, we can assume the two circles are centred at $(0, 0)$ and $(a, b)$ $a = x_2 - x_1$ and $b = y_2 - y_1$. The slope of the line passing through the two centres is $b/a$; note, $a \neq 0$ as $x_1 \neq x_2$. As the $y$-intercept of the line is $0$, the equation of the line which passes through them is $y = \frac{b}{a}x$; note that the endpoints of the blue line segment lie on this line.

As can be see from the right-angled triangle in the image below, $\sin\theta = \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, $\cos\theta=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, and $\tan\theta = \frac{b}{a}$ where $\theta$ is the angle the line $y = \frac{b}{a}x$ makes with the positive $x$-axis.

$\hspace{37mm}$[image]

In order to determine the first endpoint of the blue line segment, consider the following image.

$\hspace{37mm}$[image]

The coordinates of the first endpoint are $(a_1, b_1)$; we just need to determine what $a_1$ and $b_1$ are. Note that $R_1 = r_1$, so using the small right-angled triangle, we see that $\cos\theta = \frac{a_1}{r_1}$ so $a_1 = r_1\cos\theta$; likewise, $b_1 = r_1\sin\theta$.

In order to determine the second endpoint of the blue line segment, consider the following image.

$\hspace{37mm}$[image]

The coordinates of the second endpoint are $(a_2, b_2)$; we just need to determine what $a_2$ and $b_2$ are. Note that $R_2 = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} - r_2$, so using the smaller of the two right-angled triangles, we get the following expressions for $a_2$ and $b_2$ as we did above: $a_2 = (\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} - r_2)\cos\theta$, $b_2 = (\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} - r_2)\sin\theta$.

Combining the information deduced from the three images above, we see that, after a little bit of algebra, the endpoints of the blue segment are

$$\left(\frac{ar_1}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}, \frac{br_1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)\ \text{and}\ \left(a\left(1 - \frac{r_2}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\right), b\left(1 - \frac{r_2}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\right)\right).$$

We can undo the original horizontal and vertical shifts we did at the beginning and well as express $a$ and $b$ in terms of the original data to obtain the endpoints

$$\left(x_1 + \frac{(x_2 - x_1)r_1}{\sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2}}, y_1 + \frac{(y_2 - y_1)r_1}{\sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2+(y_2 - y_1)^2}}\right)$$

$$\text{and}$$

$$\left(x_2 - \frac{(x_2 - x_1)r_2}{\sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2}}, y_2 - \frac{(y_2 - y_1)r_2}{\sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2}}\right).$$

Note, these formulae give the correct endpoints even in the case where $x_1 = x_2$.

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation!